# Crawling depth automation

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

My site contain 3 levels.

- Country

  - City

    - Street

I want to scrape the data from all the street pages. For this I have built a spider.
Now how do I get from Country to streets without adding a million URL's in the start_url field.

Do I build a spider for country, one for city and one for street? 
Isn't the whole idea of Crawling that the crawler follows all links down to a certain depth?

Adding DEPTH_LIMIT = 3 to the settings.py file did not change anything.

I start the crawl by: scrapy crawl spidername

---

EDIT

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from winkel.items import WinkelItem

class DmozSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["mydomain.nl"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.mydomain.nl/Zuid-Holland"
    ]

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('*Zuid-Holland*', )), callback='parse_winkel', follow=True),)

    def parse_winkel(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//ul[@id="itemsList"]/li')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
        item = WinkelItem()
        item['adres'] = site.xpath('.//a/text()').extract(), site.xpath('text()').extract(), sel.xpath('//h1/text()').re(r'winkel\s*(.*)')
        items.append(item)
        return items
```

Comment: What do you mean by "did not change anything."? What's your current spider's behaviour? Can you share some come so we can advise better? @alecxe's suggestion on `CrawlSpider` is probably the way to go

Comment: I've added my script, the spider is now not returning any hits, when I remove the rule there is also no hit but when I change CrawlSpider into Spider it works fine.

Comment: Edit: working fine now. Had a typo in 'allowed domains'. Thanks alecxe  and paul t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of `CrawlSpider`, define [Rules](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules) with [Link Extractors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html) for countries, cities and streets.

For example:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('country', )), callback='parse_country'),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('city', )), callback='parse_city'),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('street', )), callback='parse_street'),
    )

    def parse_country(self, response):
        self.log('Hi, this is a country page! %s' % response.url)

    def parse_city(self, response):
        self.log('Hi, this is a city page! %s' % response.url)

    def parse_street(self, response):
        self.log('Hi, this is a street page! %s' % response.url)
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I really need the rules? How do I write an 'allow all' for example? The response is always 0, even when I put * in there..

Comment: @Thijs I've suggested using rules just to have 3 different callbacks for different types of links. This is how I understood the question, probably I didn't get it right.

Comment: I think your reply is very useful, just need to tweak my spider a little and all should be working.